# Creating Pandas Dataframe from OS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-os

I am trying to create a dataframe from `os.walk()`. Here is a sample of what my folder structure could look like.

```
Top Folder1
---File1

Top Folder2
 ---File2
 ---File3
 ---File4
```

I would like to make a DataFrame like so:

```
   Path          File_Name
0  Folder1_Path   File1
1  Folder2_Path   File2
2  Folder2_Path   File3
3  Folder2_Path   File4
```

I can get the Path of the folders, and the file names, but I cant find a way to combine them into a dataframe. I've tried `concat` and `append` into empty DataFrames to no avail and have even tried creating multiple `Series` and put them into a single DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
import os.path

for root,dirs,files in os.walk('Y:\\', topdown=True):
    if len(files) > 0:
        print(root) #Gets the Folder Path
        print("---", files) #Creates a List of the files
```

How would I get the `root` in one column of a DataFrame and `files` in another column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

res = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Y:\\', topdown=True):
    if len(files) > 0:
        res.extend(list(zip([root]*len(files), files)))

df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Path', 'File_Name']).set_index('Path')
```

edit: Actually I think you don't need the `list()` in the `zip`. both should work `res.extend(zip([root]*len(files), files))`

**Explanation:**

the DataFrame class can receive multiple type of inputs. one that is easy to understand is a `list` of `tuple`.

the length of each tuple will be the number of columns of your final DataFrame. Also, when loop are involve, appending / extending list is super efficient.

example:

```
tuple1 = (1, 2)
tuple2 = (110, 230)
all_list = [tuple1, tuple2]
pd.DataFrame(all_list)
Out[4]: 
     0    1
0    1    2
1  110  230
```

you can append to that format as much as you want:

```
for i in range(100):
    all_list.append((i, i))

pd.DataFrame(all_list)
Out[19]: 
       0    1
0      1    2
1    110  230
2      0    0
3      1    1
4      2    2
5      3    3
...
```

since you know you are passing tuple of length 2, you can pass columns names:

```
pd.DataFrame(all_list, columns=['path', 'file']).head()
Out[21]: 
   path  file
0     1     2
1   110   230
2     0     0
3     1     1
4     2     2
```

in the example you gave us, root is always of length 1 and files can be whatever size. using zip, I create tuple of length 2 (root, file) for each file in the root. since you don't know how many files there are per root, you can use `[root]*len(files)` to adjust the length of root to match the length of files

```
list(zip(["a"]*len(tuple1), tuple1))
Out[6]: 
[('a', 1), ('a', 2)]
```

extending it to the result list just add tuples to the resulting list.

Comment: I had a feeling i would have to do some multiplication haha! Thank you a million. If you have the time, I always like to get behind the mind of the person who answers my question. Could explain the solution or how you arrived to it? I'll be "reverse engineering" it best I can

Comment: Beautiful Explanation!

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, can't edit the previous. What do the brackets around `[root]` do? Without them it takes each part of the `root` instead of the full `root`. is there any documentation on that? Cannot find any.

Comment: root is a string, I just put it in a list. you cant multiply a string, but you can multiply a list